# How to remove Children from an AbsoluteLayout in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: children, removechild, xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

In my app I use a `Xamarin.Forms` `AbsoluteLayout`. I have a custom menu bar. When I clicked on a menu button, the main content (a `View`) of my `AbsoluteLayout` is supposed to be replaced.

So far I can only achieve that by adding a new child and setting its layout bounds using `Children.Add()` and `SetLayBounds()`. But this way I'm adding more and more children and never remove them.

What is the proper way to remove a child from an `AbsoluteLayout`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.Children` implements `IList<View>` (and `ICollection<View>`, `IEnumerable<View>`, `Ienumerable`) so you can use at your best convenience:

- `layout.Children.RemoveAt (position)`,
- `layout.Children.Remove (view)`,
- `layout.Children.Clear ()`

provide you know the index of your view in `.Children`, you can also replace the element in place:

```
layout.Children[position] = new MyView ();
```

but that gives you less options than the `Children.Add (...)` overrides and you'll have to use `SetLayoutBounds` and `SetLayoutFlags`.

Comment: Thanks, just found that myself! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet that uses the RemoveAt method of the AbsoluteLayout.Children collection.

Alternatively you can use the Remove(View) method if you have a variable reference.

```
        StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
        };
        //
        AbsoluteLayout objAbsoluteLayout = new AbsoluteLayout()            
        {
        };
        //
        BoxView objBox1 = new BoxView()
        {
            Color = Color.Red,
            WidthRequest = 50,
            HeightRequest = 50,
        };
        objAbsoluteLayout.Children.Add(objBox1, new Point(100,100));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children Count : " + objAbsoluteLayout.Children.Count);
        //
        BoxView objBox2 = new BoxView()
        {
            Color = Color.Green,
            WidthRequest = 50,
            HeightRequest = 50,
        };
        objAbsoluteLayout.Children.Add(objBox2, new Point(200, 200));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children Count : " + objAbsoluteLayout.Children.Count);
        //
        Button objButton1 = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Remove First Child"
        };
        objButton1.Clicked += ((o2, e2) =>
            {
                if (objAbsoluteLayout.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    // To Remove a View at a specific index use:-
                    objAbsoluteLayout.Children.RemoveAt(0);
                    //
                    DisplayAlert("Children Count", objAbsoluteLayout.Children.Count.ToString(), "OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Invalid", "There are no more children that can be removed", "OK");
                }
            });

        //
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objAbsoluteLayout);
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton1);
```